# how to allow autostart permission like whatapp app for ionic application

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, ionic2, onesignal

I have an application developed with ionic now I have a problem when starting the device for some phone notifications do not arrive until I open the application. I debug the application with android studio I found that the device receives the notification but the system does not allow the reception of notifcations because the application is not allowed after the boot to start; you have to go to the settings to allow the application to run to receive notifications in background.My question is how I can allow the application with ionic to have permission to do the autostart after the boot as c is the case of whatsapp. If there is also with android it's welcome

Answer (score 0):

You can do perform the task using Ionic Autostart Plugin

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/autostart/

As per your question, the plugin should solve the issue.

Comment: I tried this plugin but it does not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Manufacturers white list some apps like facebook and whatsapp rest of the app user should enable auto start permission.

There is no way to enable auto start permission.Only way to make it possible is showing auto start dialogue box take user to the auto start permission activity.

I have created one plugin you can have a look

https://github.com/saty932/cordova-plugin-autostart-permission